# install asterisk web interface

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I have installed Asterisk on ubuntu 14.04 LTS with:

sudo apt-get install asterisk

and It is running on my system, some logs :

root@<>:~# asterisk -rvv

Privilege escalation protection disabled!
See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/x/1gKfAQ for more details.
Asterisk 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1, Copyright (C) 1999 - 2013 Digium, Inc. and others.
Created by Mark Spencer 
Asterisk comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; type 'core show warranty' for details.
This is free software, with components licensed under the GNU General Public
License version 2 and other licenses; you are welcome to redistribute it under
certain conditions. Type 'core show license' for details.

Connected to Asterisk 11.7.0~dfsg-1ubuntu1 currently running on <> (pid = 5086)

Now I need to install Asterisk web interface. How can I do it

Answer (score 0):

First you have determine which web interface you want to install.

For example, here are instructions for freepbx:

http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FOP/Installing+FreePBX+13+on+Debian+8.1

Answer (score 0):

Ashraf

You can use a Snep. It is telephony web interface for Asterisk.

Link: http://snep.com.br/en/

Regards.